# Magento SQL statement not returning expected results

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm running Magento 1.7.0.2:

I'm trying to retrieve all the columns from a custom table using PHP & SQL, but the results returned are not what I expected or usually get:

```
$connection = $this->_getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " .  $this->_getTableName('my_custom_table_name') . " cped
        WHERE  cped.id = ?";
$results = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($id));
print_r($results); //this only prints out a single value

public function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
     return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
}

public function _getTableName($tableName){
     return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
}
```

The issue is, this only returns the first column (i.e in this case id) even though I've used the

```
Select *
```

Statement, which usually works perfectly fine. Coincidentally, if I try specify the column names that I'm interested in using:

```
Select id, name, sku, custom_value
```

It only returns the first value, so whichever column I specify first is the value it returns.

If I try running this same statement in PHPMyAdmin, it returns the expected results perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `array($id)`? what you are passing here.

Comment: `$id` in this instance is the primary key of the table, its surrounded by `array()` because usually there are a few more values parsed in there for `WHERE, ORDER BY` etc. though in this instance it could be left out.

Running it without the `array()` returns identical results.

Comment: Thanks @moose. this is something new for me. that's why I asked to u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is what `fetchOne` does. It gets the first record. Notice the `One` in the function name.
Try using `fetchAll`.

Comment: Thanks Marius, `fetchAll` does seem to do the trick! It's strange though, fetchOne usually fetches the whole record for me, i.e I still have access to any of the columns that record contains, in this instance though it limited me to one column only.. Any idea what may cause that behavior?

Comment: Sorry, NO idea. But I have a pointer. Don't use direct sql statements to fetch data from tables. Use the models in combination with `load()` method. It's safer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Marius, the reason I'm using direct statements however is due to the nature of this data size, using SQL with `read_only` allows me to analyze the data much faster than using ORM. This one has really got me puzzled, thanks though, appreciate the input!

Comment: Ok. I get your reasons. You are right. The ORM is not that fast.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was mistaken about the functionality of the direct SQL statements `fetchOne` will indeed fetch only one column result from the statement, the `fetchRow` query will return every column in that table.